# How do I get the subscript of an array number to read on the console after calculating highest and lowest intervals?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to display which 'Track' number was calculated as the longest an the shortest. I am not sure what the call for such an integer would be. At the moment my program just calls 0 which was my starting value for both. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the section of the code I am talking about. There are 12 items in the array.

```
longest = albumlength[0];
for (count = 1; count < Num_Tracks; count++)
    if (albumlength[count] > longest)
        longest = albumlength[count];

shortest = albumlength[0];
for (count = 1; count < Num_Tracks; count++)
    if (albumlength[count] < shortest)
        shortest = albumlength[count];

int total = 0;
int average;

for (int count = 0; count < Num_Tracks; count++)
    total += albumlength[count];
average = total / Num_Tracks;

cout << endl;

cout << "The longest track is #" << albumlength[longest] << " at ";
displayTime(longest);
cout << "The shortest track is #" << albumlength[shortest] << " at ";
displayTime(shortest);
cout << "The total length of the album is: ";
displayTime(total);
cout << "The average length of a track is: ";
displayTime(average);
```

Comment: Using algorithms:  `auto pr = std::minmax_element(albumlength, albumlength + Num_Tracks); shortest = pr.first - albumlength; longest = pr.second - albumlength;`

Answer (score 1):

The code is computing the actual longest and the shortest value, and then you're using the value as the index of the track number. Which makes no sense.

If you want to figure out "which 'Track' number was calculated", then do exactly that: keep track of the track number itself, instead of the actual shortest or longest value:

```
longest = 0;
for (count = 1; count < Num_Tracks; count++)
    if (albumlength[count] > albumlength[longest])
        longest = count;
```

Now `longest` is the number of the longest track, and not the actual value of the longest track. Do the same for the shortest track.

Comment: Well I want to do both. I want to call the length of the track stored in the array as well as the 'Track' number, but I get what you are saying. Thanks. I got it figured out.

Comment: Once you have the track number, `albumlength[trackNumber]` gives you the longest or the shortest length. You only need to keep track of the track number.